# equivalent for the SQL IN operator?

Tags: .net

Given the following query:

```
Select * from myTable where stringField in ('A','B','C')
```

I'll be pulling items from a db, and haven't yet decided if I will store them in a list, or an array, or some other collection object, but ideally want something built in (no custom class), and without manual iteration.

Focus is on performance and code maintainability.

What would be the most efficient way to do this in .net?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way would be [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357185) (.NET 3.5 upwards). It should also be performing well, although I have not benchmarked.

Example:

```
var list = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var matches = myTable.Where(o => list.Contains(o.stringField));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchItems = new [] {"A", "B", "C"};

var query = from c in myTable
            where searchItems.Contains(c.stringField)
            select c;
```

This if it is about LINQ 2 SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a Linq Intersect with a custom Equality Comparer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302032

Comment: That seems like too complicated solution for something as simple as this.